# Creating a Processing library without Eclipse

Tags: java, processing

The official [guidelines](https://github.com/processing/processing/wiki/Library-Guidelines) for creating a Processing library say to use the [Eclipse template](https://github.com/processing/processing-library-template), but to be honest I'd rather eat my left leg.

Is it possible to build a Processing library using, say, just Maven? What would be a working minimum configuration?

Comment: [Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393)

Comment: I've remove the request for an off-site resource, is this any better?

Comment: willing to work without eclipse is a motive for reopening for me.

Comment: Did you ever get this figured out?

Answer (score 1):

This question is still a bit broad, but I'll try to answer in a general sense.

A couple things worth mentioning:

- Processing can be used as a Java library. There isn't much special about it from this perspective. It's just a Java library.
- A Processing library is really just a Java library that uses the functions defined in Processing. You usually do this through a `PApplet` instance.
- Every sketch is a `PApplet` instance.
- Processing can be used by Maven. Googling "Processing Maven" returned [this](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.processing/core/3.3.6) result.

So, to create a Processing library that you build with Maven, you'd do the following:

- Use the above Maven dependency to add the Processing library to your classpath.
- Create a class that takes a `PApplet` instance and does whatever you want with it. I'd start simple: create a class that just draws a basic shape.
- Export that class as a `.jar` and then either drag it directly onto the Processing editor or package it up in the standard Processing library directory structure.
- Use that library from your Processing code by importing your class, passing `this` into the class, and calling whatever functions you've defined.

Note that even if you aren't using Eclipse, you can still look through the Eclipse template to see how the project is setup.

Shameless self-promotion: [here](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/java/processing-in-java) is a guide on using Processing as a Java library.